# error cannot convert 'coll' (type 'std::__cxx11::list<char>') to type 'const char&'

Tags: c++, templates, generics, stl

here I'm trying to implement a generic function to print all elements  of a container
but I am getting following errors,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
void print_elements(const T& coll)
{
    for (const auto& elem : coll)
    {
    std::cout << elem << ' ';
    }
}

int main()
{
    list<char> coll; // list container for character elements

    //appenading a to z using lists
    for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; ++i)
    {
        coll.push_back(i); //using the push back function 
    }

    for (auto elem : coll)   // in this case we have to use a range based for loop
    {       
    cout << elem << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << coll.size();

    print_elements<char>(coll);  
    return 0;
}
```

I am also getting these errors:

> candidate: 'template void print_elements(const T&)'  void
>   print_elements(const T& coll) template argument deduction/substitution
>   failed:
>
> no matching function for call to
>   'print_elements(std::__cxx11::list&)'
>   print_elements(coll);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in the following line

```cpp
print_elements<char>(coll);
```

because you specify that the template function parameter is of type `char` but you `coll` is **not** of type `char` but of type `std::list<char>`.

Therefore, you need to either pass correct parameter type like:

```cpp
print_elements< std::list<char> >(coll);
```

or let the [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) determine template arguments types automatically like:

```cpp
print_elements(coll);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in this line

```
     print_elements<char>(coll);
```

Change this to

```
     print_elements<list<char>>(coll);
```

or you may put like this

```
     print_elements(coll);
```